# Does it make sense to have the dependent variable in growth rates or rather in levels?

Tags: panel-data, random-walk

I am currently investigating the impact of uncertainty on investment dynamics. I have an unbalanced panel data set (approximately 100,000 observations). To study the relation between investment and uncertainty I use the following equation: 
 [image: another]

where the dependent variable indicates the growth rate (change) of fixed assets over total assets. The second term of the equation (first of the right-hand side) indicates firm fixed effects, the third term is the uncertainty level (time independent) and $X$ represents additional controls at the firm level.

In a recent discussion a colleague pointed out the implications of having the investment in growth rates. He stated that I am assuming that investment follows a random walk since investment growth rate by definition is the difference between the levels at t and t-1:

[image: another]

where $\rho$ is 1 by construction. Is this statement accurate? Is there any literature on whether it is best to use panel data investment in levels rather than in growth rates?

Comment: What is panel data investment? Can you clarify/grammatically correct your question?

Comment: I just have done so. Hope I have clarified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like that you are using a panel data model structure but I wouldn't use it to model change in a ratio...ever! First of all, ratios are relative metrics which blur useful information wrt differences in absolute magnitudes between the units of analysis (the cross-sections). Moreover, ratios in and of themselves can create exploding outliers at both ends of the scale whenever inputs into the calculation differ dramatically in magnitude. This simple observation renders a *change* metric virtually meaningless as it's a relative measure derived from a relative measure. Good references discussing these issues are Aitchison's *Statistical Analysis of Compositional Data* or, more recently, Pawlovsky-Glahn, et al's, *Modelling and analysis of compositional data*.

To me, it would make more sense to model fixed assets with an hierarchical, longitudinal growth model. Given that the *levels* will differ between the units of analysis, a normalizing transformation such as the natural log will help to minimize these between unit differences and, thereby, minimize the chances of obtaining spurious results.

The literature on hierarchical panel data models is huge. For your purposes it shouldn't matter if the discussion is about education, marketing, economics or finance since the only thing that really changes is the nature of the DV. A good intro is Judith Singer's paper *Using SAS PROC MIXED to Fit Multilevel Models, Hierarchical Models, and Individual Growth Models* (http://mumford.albany.edu/downloads/MLM_workshop_2016/singer.pdf). Forget the 'SAS' part, it's simply a great, short introduction to HLMs. Her book *Applied Longitudinal Data Analysis* goes much deeper into the issues. Lee Cooper's book *Market Share Analysis* has many suggestions for fitting such models with a particular focus on modeling elasticies as well as fitting differing patterns in the relationships between the IVs and DV (http://www.anderson.ucla.edu/faculty/lee.cooper/MCI_Book/BOOKI2010.pdf). Another valuable reference is Gelman and Hill's *Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models*. Of course, the classic, theoretical treatment is Wooldridge's *Econometric Analysis of Cross Section and Panel Data* but it has the strong limitation that it doesn't descend into the trenches of applied practice and concerns. Finally, I like Baltagi's *Econometric Analysis of Panel Data* for his treatment of some of the inevitable complications that can arise with panel data models.

Comment: Thanks @DJohnson for the answer and useful comments. Your third paragraph suggests that you would NOT use the ratio of fixed assets to total assets? Regarding the exploding outliers, I am winsorizing the data as suggested by much of the literature that I have read.  If you would have to use the ratio, which one would you choose, levels or differences and why? Cheers

Comment: Winsorizing is not a solution to spurious data and correlations. See Aitchison's book *The Statistical Analysis of Compositional Data* where he cites Karl Pearson in 1897 as the first to note these problems wrt compositional data. More specifically, outlier deletion doesn't solve the inherent and inevitable issues with 'enliers.' *Enliers* are spurious values that lie within the mass of the distribution but are just as invalid as outliers. One good control is to revert to a MANOVA-type framework and model both ratios and absolute levels as DVs, see paragraph 2 above.

Comment: Well definitely, like any statistical model there will be problems. But most importantly, levels or first differences of the dependent variable, and why?

Comment: We seem to be talking at cross purposes here. Just to be clear, I am *not* in favor of modeling ratios and am only including it since you seem to be quite fixed on their use. As I've tried to explain, ratios have too many problems -- just in their calculation alone. To me it makes much more sense to use the numerators of the ratios as an absolute value and normalizing them with a natural log transformation to minimize any bias due to level (mean) differences between cross sections.

Comment: ctd. The MANOVA-type framework suggestion is to use *two* DVs: normalized absolute values and the ratios you prefer. This would facilitate comparisons in terms of the relative insights and performance of each DV as well as enabling deeper understanding of which features are more important wrt the functional form of the DV.

Comment: Hi DJohnson, thanks for your answer. Indeed very useful. As I have seen, pretty much all the literature uses ratios to model investment. This comes from investment theoretical models (see Bond and Lombardi, 2006 "To buy or not to buy? Uncertainty, Irreversibility....."). Most of them use levels and only a few use the change in investment as the DV. My regressions show better/more credible results when the DV is in changes and therefore I would love to know all the potential issues that arise when the DV is in differences. Cheers

Comment: Appeals to 'the literature' can be misleading and even mistaken, particularly if you want to think for yourself and make an original contribution. Only grad students should be limited to such appeals. I think I'm confused by your use of 'levels' and 'first differences.' By levels, are you referring to ratios? And by first differences, are you referring to period-to-period change in those ratios? For all of the reasons mentioned in this thread, the latter metric is almost meaningless while the former metric is nearly so, as Aitchison clearly documents in his book.

Comment: ctd. But, if you insist on using ratios (not first differences in ratios, ever), then try reverting to a MANOVA-type framework which will allow you to understand and describe how absolute valued metrics compare with relative metrics. Enough said, at least by me.

Comment: Yes that is right, by levels I mean the ratio. Very well documented the answer and pretty clear, thanks a lot. Ratios better than first differences I take. I will read the literature to understand better why. Thanks, I have given you the points!

Comment: Thanks! I really wasn't angling for the bonus, just transferring some knowledge. Having worked in the financial industry, I'm only too well aware of the thousands of ratios that are used on an everyday basis. For the most part, these metrics are astatistical and ungrounded in any useful theory of measurement. Just consider 'technical' stock analysis where literally boatloads of nearly meaningless metrics about trends, changepoints, etc., are employed. It's kind of horrendous but you can't fight city hall, right? Again, revert to MANOVA-type, longitudinal, HLM panel models as functional form.

Comment: Thanks DJohnson, I will definitely follow your recommendation. It has been of a great value and you have definitely transfer lots of knowledge!